# foreach() not doing its job

Tags: php, regex

Can someone tell me why this is returning false, as in not breaking the script and making an alert? First, I want to match anything like a reply, like "@mark, how are ya?" in the `$comment` string and return those matches in the `$matches` array. Then, for each match found I want to search the array with usernames that had commented on the same post.

```
if( preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/', $comment, $matches) ) {
    foreach( $matches as $userName ) {
        if( in_array($userName, $commentUsers) ) {
            echo "<script>
            alert('Success!');
            </script>";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

New Code...Still returning false

```
if( preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/', $comment, $matches) ) {


        foreach( $commentUsers as $userName ) {     
if(strcmp(strtolower($userName),strtolower($matches[1])))

{print("SUCCESS!"); 
exit;}}
    }
```

Comment: Get the matched group from index 1 directly. [regex101 DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hU7qR3/1) and there is no need for `foreach` loop

Comment: what `in_array` does here? Simply check for equality of `$matches[1]` and `$commentUsers`

Comment: Ahh ok. What function would I use then to search the `$commentUsers` array for matches?

Comment: so `$commentUsers` is an array. Sorry my mistake. print the value of `$matches[1]` first

Comment: Try `foreach( $commentUsers as $userName ) { if(strtolower($userName) == strtolower($matches[1])){print...}}`

Comment: Now the problem is not in code. Just share the contents of `commentsUsers` array and actual input string. Try with sample code first instead of working directly in your actual code.

Comment: The contents of `$commentUsers` is an array of user IDs. These IDs are the IDs of users that have commented on a specific blog post. So there is no set value for `$commentUsers`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the matched group from index 1 directly. [Online demo](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=975bf1ce)

```
<?php
    $sourcestring="@mark, how are ya?";
    preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/',$sourcestring,$matches);
    echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => @mark
    [1] => mark
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php

        $source="this is @me string";
        preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/',$source,$matches);
       foreach($matches as $found){
echo "<pre>";
        print_r($found);
echo "</pre>";
       }
    ?>
```

Or

```
<?php

    $source="this is @me string";
if( preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/', $source, $matches) ) {

        if( $matches ) {
            echo "<script>
            alert('Success!');
            </script>";
            exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the problem goes either in the `preg_match` or the `$commentUsers` array structure. Can you dump that so that we can see.

I tried this code and it worked.

```
$sourcestring="@mark how are you";
preg_match('/(?<![\w@])@([\w@]+(?:[.!][\w@]+)*)/', $sourcestring,   $matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
$commentUsers[] = "mark";
foreach( $matches as $userName ) {
    if( in_array($userName, $commentUsers) ) {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Success!');
        </script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to break the loop used

```
break;
```

if you want to exit the loop and continue used :

```
continue;
```

Comment: This is not necessarily my problem because I would have at least gotten the alert without having to break the script.